# How to get data for quarter look back period

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, singlestore

I have a Loan Table having data for multiple posting from year 2000 till 2019.

I wanted to fetch data prior from current date like '31-DEC-18' for quarter lookback period of let say 4.

So the data for quarters end 30-Sep-18,30-Jun-18,31-Mar-18 & 31-dec-17 should return in Oracle and query should be dynamic for quarter lookback period.

please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the four queries below :

```
select * from loan where payment_date >= trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1; -- > 2018-12-31
select * from loan where payment_date >= trunc(trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1,'Q')-1; -- > 2018-09-30
select * from loan where payment_date >= trunc((trunc(trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1,'Q')-1),'Q')-1; -- > 2018-06-30
select * from loan where payment_date >= trunc((trunc((trunc(trunc(sysdate,'Q')-1,'Q')-1),'Q')-1),'Q')-1; -- > 2018-03-31
```